# Set Validation at TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf

How to set Validation error on textbox?
For example if user insert less than 12 word it will display.
If user insert number it will display
Validation I want to display is at Label

`<TextBox  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="41,69,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" Grid.Column="1"/>`

`<Label Content="Label" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="40,176,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>`

Answer (score 0):

use text changed event of Textbox control. you will get the number of words entered in text box using the following code

```
private void textbox1_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
 {
   string[] arrWords = textbox1.Text.Split(new char[] { ' ' });
        int count = arrWords.Length.ToString();
       if(count<12)
           {
              label1.Content="enter your error message";
           }

 }
```